# Why didn’t I get an election notification in iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, notifications

I’ve just missed the Aviation.SE voting because I only normally use the iOS app and the notification didn’t come through to the app, yet it’s there when viewing through the website.

Is this a bug? If not can we make it a feature request?

iOS app notifications - missing election notification

[image: iOS app notifications - missing election notification]

Website notifications - has election notification

[image: Website notifications - has election notification]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 11.0.2 (Build 15A421)

Comment: No, not a bug. Some types of notifications are simply not included in the API, hence not shown in the app.

Comment: fyi, if you're not a regular on that site or not participated that much, the chances are very less that you've interacted with a mod. in such case, your vote may do bad for the site.

Comment: @redhand I am a regular on the site but I access it through the app most of the time.